# Build Jenkins Job based on voting result

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scenario where on commit to repository branch let say UAT triggers a jenkins job or send email to multiple users. So when all of them click button in email or link Then is It should trigger the jenkins job build.
Can it be done if So then how. I tried to search but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)

Your job could includes an email notification to the person/group responsible for approval. The email contains a link for promotion and an optional comment for approval notes:

[image]

Once approved, the next job will run.

I suggest you, using it with a pipeline strategy.

Sources :

- https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/06/14/jenkins-delivery-pipeline-and-build-promotion-2/
- https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/another-look-jenkins-promoted-builds-plugin
- https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/continuous-integration-mobile-apps-jenkins-promoted-builds-qa-process-and-beta-distribution